# datastax cassandra.cluster.NoHostAvailable

Tags: python, cassandra, datastax, datastax-astra

I was deploying Datastax exactly as the Datastax website says and even used virtualenv but then I got an error:

```
cassandra.cluster.NoHostAvailable
```

I'm using windows 10.

I heard something about when one of my nodes go offline this error might occur but I have no idea what this means or how to fix it.

When I try to deploy Datastax exactly as the website says with bundle and token and all that I get this error:

```
raise NoHostAvailable("Unable to connect to any servers", errors)
cassandra.cluster.NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'20ad12f9-ae53-4b0a-a66a-01fd426bbdd3-us-east1.db.astra.datastax.com:29042:3fc0355c-8dc0-4fde-b81f-b55692bc4856': RuntimeError("ssl_options specify 'check_hostname', but ssl.match_hostname is not provided. Patch or upgrade Python to use this option."), '20ad12f9-ae53-4b0a-a66a-01fd426bbdd3-us-east1.db.astra.datastax.com:29042:45c38e37-2440-46d5-9312-d7846a7df2a0': RuntimeError("ssl_options specify 'check_hostname', but ssl.match_hostname is not provided. Patch or upgrade Python to use this option."), '20ad12f9-ae53-4b0a-a66a-01fd426bbdd3-us-east1.db.astra.datastax.com:29042:ed8a594e-e434-435b-ba06-f8831de2d1fb': RuntimeError("ssl_options specify 'check_hostname', but ssl.match_hostname is not provided. Patch or upgrade Python to use this option.")})
```

@Aaron I followed each step as you said and still got the same error i set ASTRADB_TOKEN and SECURE BUNDLE my code is:

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from cassandra.auth import PlainTextAuthProvider
import os

username = "token"
token = os.environ['ASTRA_DB_TOKEN']
secureBundleLocation = 
os.environ['ASTRA_DB_SECURE_BUNDLE_LOCATION']

cloud_config= {
  'secure_connect_bundle': secureBundleLocation,
  'use_default_tempdir': False,
}

auth_provider = PlainTextAuthProvider(username, token)
cluster = Cluster(cloud=cloud_config, 
auth_provider=auth_provider)
session = cluster.connect()

row = session.execute("select release_version from 
system.local").one()
if row:
  print(row[0])
else:
  print("An error occurred.")
```

the error: cassandra.cluster.NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers.
RuntimeError("ssl_options specify 'check_hostname', but ssl.match_hostname is not provided. Patch or upgrade Python to use this option.").

i cant put the whole error for some reason but this parts seems important

thanks for helping, very appriciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Which version of Python are you running on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the question!

I'm guessing you're trying out this code using Python 3.12.  That version of Python removed a function that our SSL implementation relied upon.  Fortunately we've just released a [new version of the Python driver](https://pypi.org/project/cassandra-driver/3.29.0/) which should fully support Python 3.12, including a new implementation to replace the removed function.

If you want the grisly details you can find them on [PYTHON-1331](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/PYTHON-1331), specifically [this comment](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/PYTHON-1331?focusedCommentId=55526) which discusses the function that's been removed.

Answer (score 1):

> I heard something about when one of my nodes go offline this error might occur but I have no idea what this means or how to fix it.

That's true if you're using Apache Cassandra®. For Astra DB, we mind that for you, and a connection attempt is not enough to cause a crash.

So it looks like you're trying to connect to Astra DB from Python. There's a [doc out there on how to do that](https://awesome-astra.github.io/docs/pages/develop/languages/python/#31-cassandra-drivers) in a variety of ways. I'll demonstrate how to connect with the Cassandra Python driver.

Before beginning, be sure to set environment variables for `ASTRA_DB_TOKEN` and `ASTRA_DB_SECURE_BUNDLE_LOCATION`. In Windows, that is done from the command line with the `set` command:

```
set ASTRA_DB_TOKEN=AstraCS:ASjPlHbTYourSecureTokenGoesHered3cdab53b
set ASTRA_DB_SECURE_BUNDLE_LOCATION=c:/yourbundlelocation/secure-connect-db.zip
```

For the code, you'll first need to pull in the `Cluster` and `PlainTextAuthProvider` classes from the `cassandra` library:

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from cassandra.auth import PlainTextAuthProvider
import os
```

Set `username` to the literal string "token," and then pull in the `ASTRA_DB_TOKEN` and `ASTRA_DB_SECURE_BUNDLE_LOCATION` from the environment.

```
username = "token"
token = os.environ['ASTRA_DB_TOKEN']
secureBundleLocation = os.environ['ASTRA_DB_SECURE_BUNDLE_LOCATION']
```

Next, we'll instantiate `cloud_config` and `auth_provider` objects as shown.

```
cloud_config= {
        'secure_connect_bundle': secureBundleLocation,
        'use_default_tempdir': False,
}
auth_provider = PlainTextAuthProvider(username, token)
```

We'll use those objects to instantiate `cluster` and `session` objects.

```
cluster = Cluster(cloud=cloud_config, auth_provider=auth_provider)
session = cluster.connect()
```

Now that our session is connected (hopefully), you should be able to run a quick verification query on the `system.local` table:

```
row = session.execute("select cluster_name from system.local").one()
if row:
    print("cluster name = " + row[0])
else:
    print("An error occurred.")
```

If that doesn't work for you, then please edit your question to include any relevant code and the actual error message.